# Fail to update the data in database

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, inner-join, foreign-key-relationship

I try to update the data in the database, but when I run the code, there is no error message appear, looks like its a logical error but I still don't have any clue about what is happening with my code.

Here is the code

```
 <?php

    include("conn.php");
    SESSION_START();
    if($_SESSION["loggedin"]!="true"&& $_SESSION['login'] != '')
        header("location:login.php");
    $aid = $_SESSION["usr"];
    $result = mysql_query("select r.CustomerID from customer c inner join results r on r.CustomerID = c.CustomerID where c.Username = '".$aid."' ");

    if (false === $result) {
    echo mysql_error();
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["submitbtn"]))
{
    $bookid = $_POST["bookid"];
    $LP = $_POST["LP"];
    $budget = $_POST["budget"];
    $smokep = $_POST["SmokeP"];
    $spreq = $_POST["sp_req"];
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `results` SET LP = '$LP', budget = '$budget', SmokeP = '$smokep', sp_req = '$spreq' 
                                WHERE results.BookID = '".$bookid."' and results.CustomerID = '".$result."'");  

        if (false === $query) 
        {
            echo     mysql_error();
        }

        ?>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
                alert("Amendment Saved!!");
        </script>
        <?php

}
?>
```

Is the error coming from the select query? Or the if statement for the submitbtn went wrong?

Comment: you can't use direct result variable in where condition.

Comment: Your update query is working

Comment: I hope it insert an array in yur column

Comment: Side note: are you aware that anyone could tweak `bookid` and wipe out your entire `results` table?

Comment: Well this should be like **WHERE results.BookID = '".$bookid."' and results.CustomerID = '".$row['CustomerID']."'" .... IN UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cant put session start here
You must put it on the first line after open php tag
Second
 update res='$ new_value' where ...
Tell me if it's not usefull to try another solution